# removing bad data pairs in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a large array of data, but every so often I wind up with a nan instead of a value. I need to remove these somehow. Here is an example of my dataset

```
1 2
3 4
nan 5
6 7
8 nan
9 10
```

and I would to remove the bad data to become:

```
 1 2
 3 4
 6 7
 9 10
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're just using numpy, use logical indexing:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[     1.,      2.],
              [     3.,      4.],
              [ np.nan,      5.],
              [     6.,      7.],
              [     8.,  np.nan],
              [     9.,     10.]])

# find which rows contain nans
ix = np.any(np.isnan(x), axis=1)

# remove them
x = x[~ix]
```

Which gives:

```
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.],
       [  6.,   7.],
       [  9.,  10.]])
```

This will work for arrays of any number of columns: if a row contains a NaN in at least one column, it is removed.

Alternatively, if you're using `pandas`, simply use `dropna`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.dropna()
```

Comment: I am trying to do this, and the ix array seems to work fine, but it does not seem to be removing the rows?

Comment: @user2946713 You need to assign the result to a variable, for example, `x = x[~ix]`. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
my_numpy_arr = my_numpy_arr[(my_numpy_arr==my_numpy_arr).all(1)]
```